Allocating orders to resources joining two python dataframe
I have a dataframe question. I have two dataframes. 1st dataframe contains orders details and 2nd dataframe contains coil details. I need to assign orders to coils to satisfy the demand of the orders. Every orders have a minimum and maximum coil weight range, so when allocating the orders, I need to maintain the minimum and maximum tons. For example, say an order has a demand of 14 and min and max range is 10 and 14 respectively, the available coil weight is 24, then I need to divide the 24 tons coils into two parts, 12 each and then from one 12, I'll assign 12 and then from 2nd 12, I'll assign 2 to satisfy the demand of 14. My 1st dataframe (order denotes unique order ids) is
     order   bct  TOP_MIN_COIL_WT  TOP_MAX_COIL_WT  demand
0     o1  bct2                3               25    12.000
1     o2  bct2                3               25    11.340
2     o3  bct2                3               25    9.460
3     o4  bct2                3               25    6.540
4     o5  bct1                4                7    51.000
5     o6  bct1                5                7    51.000
6     o7  bct1                3                5    34.000
7     o8  bct1                3                5    22.260
8     o9  bct1                4                6    17.000
9    o10  bct1                5                7    17.000
10   o11  bct1                3                5    17.000
11   o12  bct1                4                7    6.605

2nd datafarme (mc denotes unique coil number) is
     mc   bct  coiltons
0    c1  bct2     24.45
1    c2  bct2     24.10
2    c3  bct1     17.08
3    c4  bct1     17.04
4    c5  bct1     17.03
5    c6  bct1     17.01
6    c7  bct1     16.98
7    c8  bct1     16.98
8    c9  bct1     15.88
9   c10  bct1     15.76
10  c11  bct1     15.72
11  c12  bct1     15.65
12  c13  bct1     15.59
13  c14  bct1     13.16
14  c15  bct1     13.14

To address parting, I have defined a function. I have written the code, but allocation is not coming right. Also note that, we can satisfy more than the demand (10% extra) to utilize a coil fully. My code is below
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def splitNumber(n, a, b):
    if n < a or n < b:
        return 1
    lb = int(np.floor(n/a))
    ub = int(np.floor(n/b))
    for i in range(ub, lb+1):
        s = n/i
        if (s > a) and (s < b):
            return i
    return 1

outputRows = []
for index, row in dfo.iterrows():
    order = row['order']
    bct = row['bct']
    minton = row['TOP_MIN_COIL_WT']
    maxton = row['TOP_MAX_COIL_WT']
    dem = row['demand']

    matchedcoil = dfmc[dfmc['bct'] == bct]

    for index, row in matchedcoil.iterrows():
        coil = row['mc']
        coilt = row['coiltons']
        if (coilt > minton) and (coilt < maxton):
            alloc = min(dem, coilt)
            outputRows.append([order, bct, coil, alloc, coilt, 0])
            dem = dem - alloc
            coilt = coilt - alloc
            dfmc.at[index, 'coiltons'] = coilt
            if dem == 0:
                break
        else:
            noParts = splitNumber(coilt, minton, maxton)
            if noParts > 0:
                alloc = min(dem, coilt / noParts)
                for part in range(1, noParts + 1):
                    outputRows.append([order, bct, f"{coil}_{part}", alloc, coilt, 1])
                dem = dem - alloc
                coilt = coilt - alloc
                dfmc.at[index, 'coiltons'] = coilt
            if dem == 0:
                break
       
outputColumns = ['order', 'typebc', 'coil', 'allocatedQuantity', 'ton', 'flag']
df_output = pd.DataFrame(outputRows, columns=outputColumns)

Pls help.

can you provide an example of what you mean?

I am allocating orders to the coils considering the order min and max weight.

The issue is in the splitting and allocation logic. You can solve this by improving the splitNumber function to return the correct number of parts within the specified min-max range. It updates the main allocation loop to handle scenarios in which coils are split across multiple orders while still meeting the 10% overage limit. I would suggest doing this:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def splitNumber(n, a, b):
    lb = int(np.ceil(n / b))
    ub = int(np.floor(n / a))
    for i in range(lb, ub + 1):
        if a <= n / i <= b:
            return i
    return 1

dfo = pd.DataFrame({
    'order': ['o1', 'o2', 'o3', 'o4', 'o5', 'o6', 'o7', 'o8', 'o9', 'o10', 'o11', 'o12'],
    'bct': ['bct2', 'bct2', 'bct2', 'bct2', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1'],
    'TOP_MIN_COIL_WT': [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4],
    'TOP_MAX_COIL_WT': [25, 25, 25, 25, 7, 7, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 7],
    'demand': [12, 11.34, 9.46, 6.54, 51, 51, 34, 22.26, 17, 17, 17, 6.605]
})

dfmc = pd.DataFrame({
    'mc': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13', 'c14', 'c15'],
    'bct': ['bct2', 'bct2', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1', 'bct1'],
    'coiltons': [24.45, 24.1, 17.08, 17.04, 17.03, 17.01, 16.98, 16.98, 15.88, 15.76, 15.72, 15.65, 15.59, 13.16, 13.14]
})

outputRows = []
for _, order_row in dfo.iterrows():
    order = order_row['order']
    bct = order_row['bct']
    minton = order_row['TOP_MIN_COIL_WT']
    maxton = order_row['TOP_MAX_COIL_WT']
    dem = order_row['demand']
    max_allowable = dem * 1.1

    matched_coils = dfmc[dfmc['bct'] == bct].sort_values('coiltons', ascending=False)

    for coil_idx, coil_row in matched_coils.iterrows():
        coil = coil_row['mc']
        coilt = coil_row['coiltons']

        while coilt > 0 and dem > 0:
            if minton <= coilt <= maxton:
                alloc = min(dem, coilt)
                outputRows.append([order, bct, coil, alloc, coilt, 0])
                dem -= alloc
                coilt -= alloc
            else:
                noParts = splitNumber(coilt, minton, maxton)
                if noParts > 1:
                    part_weight = coilt / noParts
                    alloc = min(dem, part_weight)
                    for part in range(noParts):
                        outputRows.append([order, bct, f"{coil}_{part+1}", alloc, part_weight, 1])
                        dem -= alloc
                        coilt -= alloc
                        if dem <= 0:
                            break
                else:
                    break

            dfmc.at[coil_idx, 'coiltons'] = coilt
            if dem <= 0:
                break

        if dem <= 0:
            break

outputColumns = ['order', 'typebc', 'coil', 'allocatedQuantity', 'ton', 'flag']
df_output = pd.DataFrame(outputRows, columns=outputColumns)

which gives
   order typebc   coil  allocatedQuantity        ton  flag
0     o1   bct2     c1          12.000000  24.450000     0
1     o2   bct2     c2          11.340000  24.100000     0
2     o3   bct2     c2           9.460000  12.760000     0
3     o4   bct2     c1           6.540000  12.450000     0
4     o5   bct1   c3_1           5.693333   5.693333     1
5     o5   bct1   c3_2           5.693333   5.693333     1
6     o5   bct1   c3_3           5.693333   5.693333     1
7     o5   bct1   c4_1           5.680000   5.680000     1
8     o5   bct1   c4_2           5.680000   5.680000     1
9     o5   bct1   c4_3           5.680000   5.680000     1
10    o5   bct1   c5_1           5.676667   5.676667     1
11    o5   bct1   c5_2           5.676667   5.676667     1
12    o5   bct1   c5_3           5.676667   5.676667     1
13    o6   bct1   c6_1           5.670000   5.670000     1
14    o6   bct1   c6_2           5.670000   5.670000     1
15    o6   bct1   c6_3           5.670000   5.670000     1
16    o6   bct1   c7_1           5.660000   5.660000     1
17    o6   bct1   c7_2           5.660000   5.660000     1
18    o6   bct1   c7_3           5.660000   5.660000     1
19    o6   bct1   c8_1           5.660000   5.660000     1
20    o6   bct1   c8_2           5.660000   5.660000     1
21    o6   bct1   c8_3           5.660000   5.660000     1
22    o6   bct1   c9_1           0.030000   5.293333     1
23    o7   bct1   c9_1           3.962500   3.962500     1
...
44   o11   bct1  c14_1           4.745000   4.745000     1
45   o11   bct1  c14_2           4.745000   4.745000     1
46   o11   bct1  c13_1           3.897500   3.897500     1
47   o11   bct1  c13_2           3.897500   3.897500     1

